# getting 'Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'. Error in connection string .net

Tags: c#

I have this Connection string in appsetting:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "con": "Server=test.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=testQA;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=test;Password=test!@#;TrustServerCertificate=False;"
},
```

But I am getting this error:

```
   Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Keyword not 
   supported: 'initial catalog'.'
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String 
   connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
```

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: @LinkedListT SQL Server.

Comment: Please post a complete repro.  That connection string looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *connection string* must be like this.

```
"con":"Server=tcp:{your_server}.database.windows.net,1433;Database={your_database};User ID={your_user_name};Password={your_password_here};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-troubleshoot-connectivity#check-your-connection-string)

Comment: "Database" and "Initial Catalog" are interchangable.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1